# vba replace msgbox with userform

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to replace a msgbox with a userform, but when i show the userform it has no data in the textbox like it had in the msgbox, do i need to add some code to the textbox? here is what i have done

```
Sub unknown()
    Dim iListCount As Integer
    Dim iCtr As Integer



    ' Turn off screen updating to speed up macro.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Get count of records to search through (list that will be deleted).
    iListCount = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through the "master" list.
    For Each x In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    ' Loop through all records in the second list.
        For iCtr = iListCount To 1 Step -1
            ' Do comparison of next record.
            ' To specify a different column, change 1 to the column number.
            If x.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCtr, 1).Value Then
                ' If match is true then delete row.
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCtr, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next iCtr
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If r.Value > "" Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & r.Value
        End If
    Next r
    ' this msgbox works ok
    'MsgBox msg, vbOKOnly, "Unknown servers"

    frmunknownservers.Show
    Textunknownservers.Text = msg

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing Textunknownservers is the name of a Label in the form? You need to qualify it with the form that it's in. Also, you need to set the text before you show the form unless you have ShowModal set to false on the form. Otherwise the text won't be set until after the user closes the form.

```
frmunknownservers.Textunknownservers.Text = msg
frmunknownservers.Show
```

For better encapsulation, you can create a method within the form to show the form and display a message. This Sub would go in your form's code:

```
Public Sub ShowWithMessage(msg As String)
    Textunknownservers.Text = msg
    Me.Show
End Sub
```

Then to display your form, you would write this.

```
frmunknownservers.ShowWithMessage "Hello, world"
```